# Identifying newly inserted Values from database

Tags: c#, sql

Here is my problem.

I have two applications that share same database. What Application 1 insert some values(row) to database table1.

I need to fire (Trigger) event to get newly inserted values(row) to table1 from application2 once Table1 is updated.

I have some signs with SqlDependency but didn't know it is the best way and Never use it before .

Help me

Comment: Please rephrase the question to make it clear, as it stands rights now it makes no sense.

Comment: whatr are you using as a primary key?

Comment: The mechanism behind `SqlDependency` is at least deprecated and maybe already removed from newer versions of SQL Server. [SQL Server Service Broker](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522893.aspx) is probably the best way to go if you want to use the database. Another option might be a out of band notification, for example a web service call from the inserting application to the other application, but depending on your scenario this may be complex or impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Many designers include the following columns in every table CreateDT, CreateBY.  (You can also include a ModifiedDT, ModifiedBY columns).  These columns are exactly what you would expect, the datetime of the row creation and the "agent" that created the row.

So if you had these two columns in the table then application2 could poll the db with the following command to see last change and take action if it was new

```
  SELECT *
  FROM table1
  WHERE CreateBY = 'Application1'
  ORDER BY CreateDT DESC
```

You would also keep track of the last process record and add that to the query to only get results when something has happened.

```
  SELECT *
  FROM table1
  WHERE CreateBY = 'Application1'
    AND CreateDT > @lastprocesed
  ORDER BY CreateDT DESC
```

Comment: Polling is a terrible inefficient solution.

Comment: @DanielBrückner - I like how you say that without any knowledge of the architecture.

Comment: Isn't this almost an tautology? Are there real cases where polling is more efficient than explicitly notifying the other party?

Comment: @DanielBrückner - There are real cases where there is no other way to do it.  In fact, most of them (every webapp for example)

Comment: Of course, if a notification is not possible, you have no choice anyway. But I don't think web apps are a good example because today there is XMLHttpRequest. And the traditional long polling - of course still a kind of low frequency polling - is quite a bit different from hitting the database again and again to look for changes.

Comment: @DanielBrückner - Just changing the name does not change that it is a form of polling.  Polling is polling.

Comment: But the difference is that you usually make a single poll request and you immediately get something or not, while with long polling you make one request and either get something immediately or, if there is nothing, get something in the future (until the connection times out). Therefore if changes happen frequently enough long polling will never waste a request while simple polling will waste all the requests when nothing interesting happened. And long polling will notify you immediately while simple polling may lack behind up to one polling interval.

Comment: @DanielBrückner - I've totally lost your point -- first you are saying polling is a terrible solution (and by association my answer is terrible) now you are extolling the virtues of certain types of polling -- just what exactly are you trying to say?

Comment: Polling is a bad choice if there are other viable alternatives. If there are no alternatives you have no choice anyway, but polling is still bad. Long polling is by its nature better than simple polling because it is a hybrid between polling and notification.

Comment: OK!  I like that-- thanks @DanielBrückner, very clear.